# How to pause Xcode update?

Tags: mac-appstore

In the App menu, I can see that it is updating. However, in the App Store updates page, it is not showing. The update is ~3GB, and I don’t have the bandwidth to spare. How can I pause/stop it?

Comment: Try reloading the App Store Updates page by for example closing the App Store application. Did it help?

Comment: I have tried closing and opening again. Let me try a reboot.

Comment: Yes, AppStore has trouble showing and updating the progress bar correctly. Select another tab and back to (Purchases?) and you should see the progress bar

Comment: @zero it only shows “iMovie update available” However, if I go to the xCode description page, there it shows “Installing"

Comment: Ah ok in this case it has it already downloaded and installs it.

Comment: @zero , in my apps page, it shows downloading 70mb of 2.5gb

Comment: OK - misread that. But somehow you must force AppStore to show the progress bar where it has the "x" to stop it. And: if you can do that and stop it, it won't probably show that until you do the tab-switch again. That is how it works here but not every time.

Comment: @Zero ah found it in the “Purchases” tab somehow.

Comment: Cool. It probably will also not show that it has stopped until you do the tab switcheridoo again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching tabs in the App Store or restart the App Store application and see if you can get it to refresh and show the progress bar + a stop button in the Updates tab. App Store can sometimes have some problems with showing the progress bar for updates.

In general it helps to switch tabs from Updates to i.e. Purchases and back again. In some cases it also fixes the issue if you close and reopen the App Store application.

Comment: I paused it from the Purchases page itself.

Comment: @xrisk Good that you got the issue solved, now you can restart the installation when you have time and spare bandwidth. Just saw your conversation with Zero now after posting the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue and what I did was the following:

1. Go to Finder -> Applications
2. Movde Xcode.app to trash. (This will alert you if you want to cancel update).
3. Agree to cancel update from alert.
4. Go to Trash -> Xcode.app, right click and click on "Put Back"
5. Re-start using Xcode and continue with your work.

If you do not wish to hamper your work while you wait for XCode to update and you are in a slow internet connection, go to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ and download latest version of xcode dmg (close to 6 GB) after you login in your apple developer account.